# SSL Client certificate verification on linphone

Tags: android, ssl, client-certificates, linphone, linphone-sdk

I was implementing secure calling from [asterisk official site tutorial](https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Secure+Calling+Tutorial)

And after a lot of effort and understanding of ssl and certificates, I have managed to secure it only 1 way.
Following was the best clue and direction:
[SSL using self signed certs on linphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31781181/linphone-android-tls-handshake-error-with-self-signed-certificate)

How can I make use of client certificates (which the above tutorial generated) to validate clients also on server; called **full ssl authentication**

I read about this setting in linphonerc file: `"verify_client_certs=1"` but I don't know where to put client certs?

Comment: Hello do you know how to disable TLS certificate verification from Android App ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Hi you can check on our wiki to more information about client certificats.
```

https://wiki.linphone.org/wiki/index.php/Security:ClientCertAuth

```
Security:ClientCertAuth

1. Creating Client certificate


    Generate a Certificate Signing Request

Creates a new private key and a certificate request with CN=username@domain

example test@test.linphone.org

    openssl req -new -keyout key.pem -out newreq.pem

    Sign the client certificate 

Creates newcert.pem certificate signed by root certificate. You will need to enter the passphrase of the cacert.pem

    openssl ca -policy policy_anything -out newcert.pem -infiles newreq.pem

Then extract the private key in a new file

    openssl rsa -in key.pem -out clientkey.pem

    Parameters for linphone

In linphonerc add path to client/key certificate

[sip]
client_cert_chain=/pathTo/newcert.pem
client_cert_key=/pathTo/clientkey.pem
```

Comment: brother!!!!... God will reward you.. You saved a lot of trouble. and just saying, I tried many times to open the link, but it was unreachable and i thought its broken lol.. but thanx. It worked like a charm (Y)

Comment: Hello do you know how to disable TLS certificate verification from Android App ?

Answer (score 0):

Please, confirm where in following command we use cacert.pem

`openssl ca -policy policy_anything -out newcert.pem -infiles newreq.pem`

also i have trying to use self signed ca certficate to setup asterisk with linphone. But i could'nt figure where in linphone app i have to put the client cert or even would it work if i just add my rootca.pem to the rootca.pem in the provided source for [linphone-android](https://github.com/BelledonneCommunications/linphone-android)

Comment: certificates are placed in folder: res->raw. rootca.pem is the root ca which will be used to authenticate the server certificates. since a certificate is generated using rootca, be it a server certificate or client certificate. you can use same rootca on both sides or different. in that case, server should have a copy of client's rootca so when client will sent its certificate during ssl handshake, server can proceed to verfication using the rootca from client.