# TLS and SRTP certificate in android linphone project

Tags: android, tls1.2, linphone, linphone-sdk

we have an Android Application with linphone library for voice calling (sip server - asterisk).

we need to switch transport mode from TCP to TLS  and change media encryption to SRTP  for secure communications.

my problem is how can i embed and use .CA and .pem certificate file in Linphone project. i searched about it but could not find any good solution.

can anybody help me and save my life ?

thank you so mouch.

Comment: Hello do you know how to disable TLS certificate verification from Android App ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

finally i found my answer , we should embed .ca file in res/raw/rootca.pem path in android project and replace with rootca.pem linphone file that copied in raw folder.

for more info you ca use following links.

[link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31781181/linphone-android-tls-handshake-error-with-self-signed-certificate) 
[link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41462750/ssl-client-certificate-verification-on-linphone)

Comment: Hi Amin, have you managed to find a solution to allow for changing the certificates without recompiling the .APK?

Comment: Hello do you know how to disable TLS certificate verification from Android App ?